# Have colors when using :make

Tags: color

When I'm using `:make`, the output doesn't have any color. The text is only white. 
But when I'm using `:!make` for a C project or `:Cargo run` for a rust project ( I also use rust.vim ) , there are colors on the output. ( the colors that the c compiler or the rust compiler have by default)

How can I make the output of `make` colorful ?

Comment: Most programs disable text coloring when output is not to a tty (citation needed). If vim could interpret ansi color escapes (provided by some plugins, no experience personally), then you might be able to override with `—color` flag or similar.

Comment: That is a bug in [cargo](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/5872)